# Is there some way to get the new APK from Google Play Store sooner?

Tags: google-play-store, apk

For example, Pokemon Go 0.57.2 was [available on apkmirror.com](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/niantic-inc/pokemon-go/pokemon-go-0-57-2-release/pokemon-go-0-57-2-android-apk-download/) for 4, 5 hours now, but still it is not on Google Play.

Is there any way to get it from official source sooner?  I mostly trust apkmirror.com, but say, what if somebody hacked into apkmirror (which I assume will be less secure than Google Play Store) and target a country in the world and serve a modified apk, or target some IP, then it will be not secure.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are taking about

> Pokemon go

in specific. Just for your information, app is still available in playstore. 
Don't know from which country you are in. I'm in India. And I can find Pokemon Go in playstore

Below Link
[Pokemon Go Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en)

2. If you talking about any playstore apps, I don't think there is any way you can download it apart from source(playstore).
   If any website found which allows to download apks . I would warn you not download it and install. Those might be injected and can cause harm to ur details and your contents in your devices.

Note: there are some apps in Google Playstore that can slow down and bring harm.

Answer (score 1):

Google has two mechanism that may be responsible for your observation:

1. A app developer can publish new apps only to a certain percentage of the users. In case of errors in the new app version the support is not taken down by a DDOS of all the users having problems.
2. Google allows to start beta-tests with closed groups (hand-picked) that get access to new versions while the rest of the users only get access to the previous version. May be the version uploaded to apkmirror is such a version.

In both cases you can do nothing to receive the update earlier.